# JavaFX Table: Label not behaving as expected

Tags: javafx, label

I'm using the following code to highlight text in a `Table` with `HBoxes` containing multiple `Labels`. But some `Labels` display ellipses instead of text. How can i force the `Labels` to appear in full width?

```
    col3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RegexMatch, String>("excerptLineTable"));
    col3.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell call(TableColumn param) {
            TableCell cell = new TableCell() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Object text, boolean empty) {
                    if (text != null && text instanceof String) {
                        HBox hbox = new HBox();
                        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
                        String str = (String) text;
                        if (txtSearchField.getText().length() > 3 && str.contains(HIGHLIGHT_START)) {
                            // Something to highlight
                            hbox.getChildren().clear();
                            while (str.contains(HIGHLIGHT_START)) {
                                // First part
                                Label label = new Label(str.substring(0, str.indexOf(HIGHLIGHT_START)));
                                label.setWrapText(false);
                                label.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                                hbox.getChildren().add(label);
                                str = str.substring(str.indexOf(HIGHLIGHT_START) + HIGHLIGHT_START.length(), str.length());
                                // Part to highlight
                                Label label2 = new Label(str.substring(0, str.indexOf(HIGHLIGHT_END)));
                                label2.setWrapText(false);
                                label2.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                                label2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: "+ HIGHLIGHT_COLOR+";");
                                hbox.getChildren().add(label2);
                                // Last part
                                str = str.substring(str.indexOf(HIGHLIGHT_END) + HIGHLIGHT_END.length(), str.length());
                                if (!str.contains(HIGHLIGHT_START)) {
                                    Label label3 = new Label(str);
                                    label3.setWrapText(false);
                                    label3.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                                    hbox.getChildren().add(label3);
                                }
                            }
                        } else if (txtSearchField.getText().length() < 1) {
                            // Remove former highlightings and show simple text
                            str = str.replaceAll(HIGHLIGHT_START, "");
                            str = str.replaceAll(HIGHLIGHT_END, "");
                            hbox.getChildren().clear();
                            Label label = new Label(str);
                            label.setWrapText(false);
                            label.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                            hbox.getChildren().add(label);
                        } else {
                            // show simple text
                            hbox.getChildren().clear();
                            Label label = new Label(str);
                            label.setWrapText(false);
                            label.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                            hbox.getChildren().add(label);
                        }
                        setGraphic(hbox);
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }
    });
```

[image]

**Solution**
Using `Labels` in a `HBox` with different background colors for each `TableView` works fine. My problem was a bug in my highlighting search and replace method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only found a rather ugly solution:

```
private static Label createNoEllipsisLabel(String pText)
{
    Label label = new Label(pText);
    double width = computeTextWidth(label.getFont(), pText, 0);
    label.setPrefWidth(width);
    label.setMinWidth(width);
    return label;
}

private static final TextLayout layout = Toolkit.getToolkit().getTextLayoutFactory().createLayout();

private static double computeTextWidth(Font font, String text, double wrappingWidth) {
    layout.setContent(text != null ? text : "", font.impl_getNativeFont());
    layout.setWrapWidth((float)wrappingWidth);
    return layout.getBounds().getWidth();
}
```

As it is copied from `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.Utils.computeTextWidth(Font, String, double)` it used very much internal APIs which is rather not a good idea.

Maybe someone other finds a better solution?

Comment: The behaviour looks strange to me, is it a bug or wanted behaviour? I hope there is also a solution via the standard API

Comment: Unfortunately your solution doesn't work for me, the Labels stay presented with elipsis...

Comment: I have not tested it inside a TableView and I think that is where the problem is: Each table cell should be resizable and can not force itself to be wider than its column. I guess using a FlowPane would be the better option. This will break your Labels into multiple lines if they exceed the cells width. But this should allow the Labels to take the space they need.

Comment: I guess the TableView is not the right control element for your use case. My last idea is to write your own custom control for this and write VirtualContainerBase Skin for this custom control.

Comment: I also thought about other control but i ned column formattig and resizing. My programm has some functionality like LogExpert [www.log-expert.de].

Comment: Ok, i finally found the problem, i used line.replaceAll(pattern, HIGHLIGHT_START + pattern + HIGHLIGHT_END); instead of patternToReplace.matcher(line).replaceAll(HIGHLIGHT_START + "$1" + HIGHLIGHT_END);. E.g. highlighting '...' run into problems... So your advice using `Label` in `HBox` in the `TableView` was right. Thanks!