# A Java advanced text logging pane for large output

Tags: java, logging, textbox, wolfram-mathematica

Mathematica comes with a simple java program that allows to inspect the communication between front end and the kernel. It's called [LinkSnooper](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/ref/java/com/wolfram/jlink/util/LinkSnooper.html) and in general it works quite nice. It looks like this

> [image]

I think I can improve the behavior and usability of the program to some extend, but to do this, I need to reimplement some parts. One fundamental piece that I need is a text pane, which has the following properties:

- it can receive a lot of data and it probably should use a fast ring-buffer so that the very first log-lines are removed when the data grows too much. Another possibility is that it automatically starts to write data to disk and possibly reloads it when the user scrolls up to see the first entries
- it should be able to handle colored text. I plan to use a simple highlighter (the log-data is actually real Mathematica syntax) on each arriving line to make reading more easy
- it doesn't need to be writable. It's OK if the text pane is read-only.

**Question:** Does something like this already exist? Currently, LinkSnooper uses a `JTextArea` underneath and before I start do write my own version, I wanted to ask whether someone has already done this.

#### Edit:

What I planned to do was to use some Logger framework because it seems natural to me that those libraries should be able to handle a lot of data. Additionally, they often provide interfaces to format the messages and you can define different handlers that can take care of different messages. What I was hoping for was that someone already has combined this with a neatly working text window that can handle large output.

Comment: no existing component that matches your need comes to mind, but if you had to make it yourself, did you have a look at JavaFX? It has nice high-level components, including the `TextFlow` in Java8. See this blog post and comments for a preview http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2013/02/14/experimenting-with-textflow-from-javafx8/

Comment: @SimonBaslé No, I didn't know JavaFX but I will have a look at it. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Simon has pointed out I would suggest using JavaFX for this task.

If you "just" need to display large amounts of log data without advanced highlighting (sub-string range highlighting), [`ListView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html) is the component for you.

It uses a virtualized layout container, so only the cells that are in the visible area of the viewport are actually rendered. This allows for lazy loading, cell recycling etc.
The `ListView` uses an [`ObservableList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) as its DataStructure. Similar to EMF `EList`, the `ObservableList`automatically notifies the `ListView` on changes in its contained data.

There are several factory methods to create an ObservableList via [`FXCollections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html) even allowing to wrap an existing `List` (e.g. `RingBuffer`).

If you need the advanced highlighting, [`RichTextFX`](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX) is probably the solution to go for as it allows detailed styling of its contained text. `RichTextFX` uses a virtualized layout, too.

---

**Edit #2**

Tom has written about this in his blog: http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2014/12/27/displaying-and-editing-large-styled-texts/

---

**Edit #1 ListView example**

JavaFX does a very good job at separating the model from the view, so we try not to mix this up and need to create two things:

1. A data class (model)
2. A `Cell` renderer for that data class (view).

First the data class:

```
public class LogData {

    private final String logMessage;
    private List<String> highlightedFragments = null;

    public LogData(String pLogMessage) {
        logMessage = pLogMessage;
    }

    public String getLogMessage() {
        return logMessage;
    }

    public List<String> getHighlightedFragments() {
        if (highlightedFragments == null) {
            doHighlight();
        }
        return highlightedFragments;
    }

    private void doHighlight() {
        List<String> highlightedParts = Collections.emptyList(); // TODO lexer
        highlightedFragments = highlightedParts;
    }
}
```

The interesting part is, that the highlighting is done on demand not on initialization. Or in other words: The lexer only performs its work, when the cell renderer requests the data.

Now the `Cell` renderer:

```
ListView<LogData> listView = new ListView<>();
listView.setCellFactory(cb -> new LogDataCell(){});

public class LogDataCell extends ListCell<LogData>
{
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(LogData item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if(empty || item == null) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        }
        else {
            List<String> fragments = item.getHighlightedFragments();
            if(fragments == null || fragments.isEmpty()) {
                setText(item.getLogMessage());
                setGraphic(null);
            }
            else {
                TextFlow textFlow = null; //TODO
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textFlow);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is not a fully working example, there are several TODOs left, but hopefully you get the idea.

If you want to add search highlighting, I described a similar approach for the TableView control element here: [JavaFX Table with highlighted text (Labels) with poor performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991719/javafx-table-with-highlighted-text-labels-with-poor-performance/26992240#26992240)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will read the links you have given.

Comment: Someone who doesn't like your answer. You still have my upvote and I briefly looked over the doc of `ListView` and it seems this is a good starting point.

Comment: RichTextFX seems to be a bit too much for me. I created a test using a normal `ListView` with a custom style `ObservableList<TextFlow>`. Let's say I want to use a simple `ObservableList<String>` to store my data and only the few cells that are currently visible in the `ListView` should be highlighted. I guess then I have to implement my own cell factory. When I want all the properties of the default cell factory for Strings, only that my one displays colored text by running and using a lexer, do you know  how to easily achieve that?

Comment: Never mix view and model, so I added a rather big edit to my answer. Hopefully you get the idea? :-)

Comment: That's why I asked, because I wanted exactly this separation of data and representation. Thank you.

Comment: I adjusted my implementation and it seems to work very nice. Unfortunately, I will have write my own lexer (jflex), since the one that comes with [Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/ref/java/com/wolfram/jlink/ui/SyntaxTokenizer.html) isn't fast enough for very long messages. Here is [a first screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vY8QZ.png). Anyway, thanks for all the help.

Comment: Always happy to help. If you just started with JavaFX you are a very fast learner ;-)

Comment: I have some glitches/lags in my listview: when I scroll very fast, then it seems not all `ListCells` are updated properly. The syntax coloring is OK, but when I hover with the mouse over a cell, it happens that another cell is highlighted instead. Additionally, selecting a cell by clicking doesn't work on all visible cells anymore. It is probably possible to reproduce this when the `updateItem` method contains a `Thread.sleep(50)` or something like that. Can you make any sense of that?

Comment: Just in case you have any idea you want to discuss, I'm online in the [Java chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java) for a while.

Comment: Sorry, I am in christmas holidays and "only" look at SO once in a while. But I posted another answer to your new question regarding this issue.