# JavaFX Text styling for dynamic objects

Tags: css, javafx

I'm using a `ListView` in [my program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27414689/1078614) with many, many styled `Text`'s. Currently, I'm doing something like this

```
case COMMENT:
  t = new Text(lexer.comment.toString());
  t.setStyle(BASE_STYLE + COMMENT_STYLE);
```

where the style is stored as java string. I do have a `global.css` in my application which is used to style some static nodes of the scene, but for the programatically created texts I don't know how to access this. I tried using `t.setId(..)` and put a style definition in the css file but this doesn't work.

Is there a way that I can store all styles for my different text types in one css and access them easily? Note that I'm creating many of those text objects.

Comment: why are you not using css-class-selectors? BTW there are Styledtext controls out there so why reinvent your own?

Comment: @tomsontom But how can I get access to my global css file when I create a text with `Text t = new Text("blub")`? When I refer to a css class with `setStyle` this doesn't have any effect. Regarding the styled text: I would like to but in the linked question I have explained what I try to do. I had a bounty of 200 for a week on it, but only one user wrote an answer.

Comment: accessing css-classes is done with getStyleclass().add("mycssclass")

Comment: At efxclipse we have control named StyledTextArea who is able to load text and color regions of it - it also uses ListView - i'll try to write a blog about it later today

Comment: @tomsontom Let me know when you did that! For my real application, itprobably would have been better to do it with swing in Java7 because this is the version *Mathematica* is shipped with and the user wouldn't have to take care of a new jre. Although JavaFX [was already included in java 1.7.0_13](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#5) I don't know in which shape it was back then.

Comment: I've blogged about it - http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2014/12/27/displaying-and-editing-large-styled-texts/ but all this needs Java8!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three ways to apply CSS styling to a JavaFX Node (or a combination of them):

1. As Tom mentioned, a `Node`s css style classes are accessed via [`Node.getStyleClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getStyleClass--). This returns an ObservableList where you can add and remove your style classes.
2. If you change a Nodes style rather often, it is better to use pseudo selectors, like `:hover` or `:active` with [`Node.pseudoClassStateChanged()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#pseudoClassStateChanged-javafx.css.PseudoClass-boolean-).
3. The third option you already discovered (`setStyle()`), but I dislike this option because moving the CSS parts into a seperate file offers many advantages.

---

For #1 and #2 you need to attach a Stylesheet to the Scene/Node, with [`Scene.getStylesheets()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#getStylesheets--) or [`Parent.getStylesheets()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#getStylesheets--), where your CSS definitions are stored. For example:

```
listView.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("myStyles.css").toExternalForm());
```

---

*Addtional info for #1:*

If you want to add the style-class `my-node` to a JavaFX Node:

```
node.getStyleClass().add("my-node");
```

now you can style that node in your CSS file:

```
.my-node {}
```

---

*Addtional info for #2:*

You can declare and use your own pseudo-class with

```
PseudoClass comment = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("comment");
node.pseudoClassStateChanged(comment, true);
node.pseudoClassStateChanged(comment, false);
```

And in your css file:

```
.my-node:comment {}
```

Comment: Grmpf.., I had it exactly as your #1 but used `".my-node"` when I added the style and wondered why it did not work.

Comment: It's always the small things that count. If this answers your question, please flag the answer accordingly ;-)