# JavaFX 2.2 built-in controls have no default style

Tags: java, css, javafx

While the CSS styling tutorials mention both default style sheet (caspian.css) and default classes for built-in controls (like .line for Line), my controls seem to lack both (checked by  debugger).

As a result, the do not react for additional custom CSS if I do not set their class explicitly, which is annoying and destroys the whole point of global CSS styling.

I would be grateful for any ideas of what may cause such behaviour.

Comment: Where do you see that the default style class for `Line` is `.line`? The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#line) says "Empty by default". `Control` subclasses have default style classes. Other nodes do not. Also, note that the default style sheet is not applied until the first `Control` is created; so if you are not using any `Control` subclasses, even the default stylesheet will not be applied.

Comment: Oh, ok. Don't know why, but I was sure that the default style class is provided (by reflection) for all node subclasses. Turns out, it is not. Makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot and sorry for a trvial question! What is the best way to close the question now?

Comment: Well... maybe we are both somewhat wrong on this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28086092/javafx-style-by-classname So it appears you can use `Line` as the selector, but not `.line`

Comment: Added answer to cover all cases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaFX, three CSS selectors are supported, which are analogous to Type Selectors, Class selectors, and ID selectors in standard CSS. It's important to be a bit careful with the word "class", which has different meanings in the Java world and the CSS world: a Java class is a CSS Type; a CSS class is set on a node via a property called `styleClass`.

The Type Selector is determined by the result of calling the method `getTypeSelector`, which is declared in the interface `Styleable`. `Node` implements this interface, and implements [`getTypeSelector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getTypeSelector--) to return

> getClass().getName() without the package name

So *any* `Node` may be styled by specifying its simple class name:

```
Label {
    -fx-text-fill: green ;
}
Line {
    -fx-stroke: red ;
}
```

etc.

CSS classes are determined by the `getStyleClass()` method in `Styleable`, which returns a list of strings. (Note that nodes may have multiple style classes, though I have never understood why this is a `List` rather than a `Set`.) By default, this list is empty, but `Control` subclasses set this value via their default skin to be the "css-ized" version of the class name (`Button` becomes `button`, `ComboBox` becomes `combo-box`, etc.). Thus

```
.label {
    -fx-text-fill: green ;
}
```

works, but

```
.line {
    -fx-stroke: red ;
}
```

does not work without previously setting the style class:

```
Line line = new Line();
line.getStyleClass().add("line");
```

Finally, ID Selectors work by specifying an id on the node. Ids are intended to be unique among all nodes in the scene graph. So you can do

```
Line line = new Line();
line.setId("my-line");
```

with

```
#my-line {
    -fx-stroke: red ;
}
```

So in your example, the style class is not set by default (`Line` is not a `Control` subclass). You must either set it "by hand", or use a type selector.

One last note: you mentioned that your line "lacked caspian.css". I'm not quite sure what that means (as `Line`s are not styled at all by the default stylesheet), but the default stylesheet is only loaded the first time a `Control` is instantiated. This is intended as a performance enhancement for scene graphs that use no controls (and so would not benefit from the default stylesheet anyway).