# JavaFX ListView rendering bug when using custom list cells

Tags: java, listview, javafx, listviewitem

I'm creating a [highlighting communication logger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27414689/1078614) which uses a `ListView` to display each message in a single cell.

[image]

It basically works, but when I scroll very fast up and down, weird things happen. As you can see I'm highlighting the cell which is currently selected and the cell where the mouse is over. After I scrolled up and down, the highlighted cells are not the ones where my mousepointer is and for some cells, I'm unable to select them by click.

I was able to reproduce this in a very simple example. Assume we have a `ListView` of strings with custom `MyListCell`'s that render those cells using a `TextFlow`. The `updateItem` method of `MyListCell` looks like this

```
@Override
  protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {

    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (empty || item == null) {
      setText(null);
      setGraphic(null);
      return;
    }

    TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow(new Text(item));
    setGraphic(textFlow);
    setText(null);
  }
```

in the initialization I just create a new observable array of strings and I set the cell factory accordingly:

```
public ObservableList<String > content = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
public ListView<String> listView;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    listView.setCellFactory(cb -> new MyListCell());
    listView.setItems(content);
    /* ... /*
```

The full working example code consists only of some files (you need to adapt the package path):

- [gui.fxml](http://hastebin.com/oyabawemic.xml)
- [GUI.java](http://hastebin.com/midehijehu.java)
- [Controller.java](http://hastebin.com/yososoqali.java)
- [MyListCell.java](http://hastebin.com/denehazari.java)
- [style.css](http://hastebin.com/ubawexicoc.css)

**Question:** Can anybody confirm this behavior and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My system is Ubuntu 14.04 with Oracle jdk 1.8.0_25

Comment: Another finding: When I replace the `TextFlow` with a simple `HBox`, then it seems that I cannot reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Basically in JavaFX creating a new `Node` and adding it to the SceneGraph is an expensive operation. This is why the `ListView` uses a virtualized layout container, reusing its cells upon viewport change instead of creating new ones.

What you should do is to reuse the `TextFlow` inside your `ListCell` or in other words: Store it as a member attribute and "only" set its children inside the `updateItem()` method.

Regarding the `TextFlow` vs `HBox`: The `TextFlow` has a rather sophisticated layouting mechanism due to the built in (word) wrapping. So if `HBox` does what you need, you should consider using it instead (of course caching it inside the ListCell).

You can try to boost this further by trying to cache the `Text` Nodes. But currently I can not offer you a simple solution for that (a `Node` in JavaFX can only be contained in a single `Parent` Node, so a simple `WeakHashMap` Cache with `computeIfAbsent` won't work)..

Comment: I tried both ways: With and without storing the rendered text in the object and reuse it. It doesn't make any difference, the `ListView` with `TextFlow` is still buggy. I guess it is really some internal properties of `TextFlow` which makes that it goes wrong. Additionally, I tried the `RichtTextFX.StyleClassedTextArea` which ended in the same issues. The reason why I decided against storing the rendered text is that it is indeed a reasonable fast operation so that it can be calculated again if someone really scrolls back in the log-view. On the other hand it would use much memory if stored.

Comment: As I guessed: TextFlow is not really meant to be used inside a ListView Cell. Or in other words: the internal layouting of TextFlow takes too much time for 20-30 cells at the same time (too much time = JavaFX Scene Pulse gets throttled). If HBox works for you, use it ;-)

Comment: Despite of topic old, have to say using HBox node, instead TextFlow solved my issue with ListView. I also, as topic starter, used updateItem() method and spend large amount of time to find this. Thanks!

Comment: 100% this is the problem of TextFlow, thanks.

Comment: But is there any way, that I could late for fully rendering of textflow on list scroll ?